# Python regex - (\w+) results different output when used with complex expression

Tags: python, regex

I have doubt on python regex operation. Here you go my sample test.

```
>>>re.match(r'(\w+)','a-b') gives an output
>>> <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f51c0033210>

>>>re.match(r'(\w+):(\d+)','a-b:1')
>>>
```

Why does the 2nd regex condition doesn't give match object though the 1st regex gives match object for a normal string match condition, irrespective of special characters is available in the string?

However, \w+ will matches for [a-z,A-Z,_]. I'm not clear why (\w+) gives matched object for the string 'a-b'. How can I check whether  the given string doesn't contain any special characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a look at the actual match will give you an idea of what happens.

```
>>> re.match(r'(\w+)', 'a-b')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002DE45D0>
>>> _.groups()
('a',)
```

As you can see, the expression matched `a`. The character sequence `\w` only contains actual *word characters*, but not separators like dashes. So you can’t actually match `a-b` using just a `\w+`.

Now in the second expression one might think that it would match `b:1` at least, given that `\w+` matches `b` and `:(\d+)` does match the `1`. However it does not happen due to how [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) works. As the documentation hints, it only tries to match *“at the beginning of `string`”*. So when using `re.match` there is an implicit `^` at the beginning of the expression that makes it only match from the start. So it actually tries to find a match starting with `a`.

Instead, you can use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) which actually looks in the whole string if it can match the expression anywhere. So there, you will get a result:

```
>>> re.search(r'(\w+):(\d+)', 'a-b:1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002E01B58>
>>> _.groups()
('b', '1')
```

For further information on the `search` vs. `match` topic, check [this section in the manual](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

And finally, if you want to match dashes too, you can use a character sequence `[\w-]` for example:

```
>>> re.match(r'([\w-]+):(\d+)', 'a-b:1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002E01B58>
>>> _.groups()
('a-b', '1')
```

Answer (score 2):

The first matches the `a` - one or more word chars.

The second is one or more word chars *immediately* followed by a `:` which there aren't...

`[a-z,A-Z,_]` (the equivalent of `\w`) means *a* to *z* and *A* to *Z* - it isn't the literal hyphen in this context, if you did want a hyphen, put it as the first or last character of a character class.

Answer (score 1):

[Match's docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.match) say

> If **zero or more characters at the beginning of string** match the
> regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject
> instance.

`match` method will return the matched object if it finds a match at the beginning of the string. `(\w+)` matches `a` in `a-b`.

```
print re.match(r'(\w+)','a-b').group()
```

will print

```
a
```

In the second case (`(\w+):(\d+)`), the actual string which gets matched is `b:1`, which is not at the beginning of the string. That's why its returning `None`.

> How can I check whether the given string doesn't contain any special characters?

I would say, the second regular expression which you have used should be enough and `match` function should be enough. I insist on `match`, since there are differences between `match` and `search` http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Remember, you